# Throttle also delays first sample

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to tame a keyboard triggered event that without throttling would fire with a very high frequency. The code below works but it also delays the first invocation of GlobalCopy by the throttling timespan. Is there a way to get the first sample without delay?

```
observableGlobalCopy = Observable
  .FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => this.GlobalCopy += h, h => this.GlobalCopy -= h);

observableGlobalCopy
    .SubscribeOnDispatcher()
    .Throttle(GlobalEventThottle)
    .Subscribe(x => GlobalCopyHandler());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var observableGlobalCopy2 = observableGlobalCopy
    .Window(() => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)))
    .Select(_ => _.Take(1))
    .Merge();
```

Comment: You could even shorten this by combining `Select` and `Merge` into a single `SelectMany`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, how about this?

```
observableGlobalCopy.Take(1)
    .Concat(
        observableGlobalCopy.Throttle(GlobalEventThottle))
    .SubscribeOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(x => GlobalCopyHandler());
```